# String occurrence ranking in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table `my_table` contains free text like

```
my_table (each line contain one row)
-----
abc def
def jsj
kfi def ldkf
kgdu abc
```

I want to have result like

```
count string
3     def
2     abc
1     ...
```

Is it possible? And what is the sql?

Answer (score 0):

If always delimited by a space then you could split the string up based on the spaces using a range of generated numbers.

Something like this

```
SELECT aString, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((some_column, ' ', units.iCnt + 10 * tens.iCnt + 100 * hundreds.iCnt), ' ', -1) AS aString
    FROM some_table,
    (SELECT 1 aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units,
    (SELECT 1 aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens,
    (SELECT 1 aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) hundreds
    WHERE LENGTH(some_column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(some_column, ' ', '')) >= (units.iCnt + 10 * tens.iCnt + 100 * hundreds.iCnt)
) sub0
```

This uses 3 cross joined selects which each generate the numbers 0 to 9, which can give the range 0 to 999 (can easily add more cross joins if there are more than 999 string in the column). This number is used with SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the string up to the X space, then SUBSTRING_INDEX is used with -1 to get the string from the previous space.

The WHERE clause is just there to only derive each string one (SUBSTRING_INDEX would otherwise get the last string multiple times).